# Npgsql Linq "where" query problem with C# DateTime and PgSql Timestamp with timezone

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, npgsql

I have no idea how to create proper linq "where" query for PostgreSql timestamp with timezone column.
In Database Model I have mapped that to DateTime.
I am using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 7.0.3.
I use function that returns me filtered data from dbset:

```
 protected IQueryable<T> ResultFiltered<T>(IQueryable<T> data, Query query)
        {
            var temp = data;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.Filter))
            {
                temp = temp.Where(query.Filter);
            }

            return temp;
        }
```

It works fine for querys like "Id = 12 AND Amount > 0" etc..
I have no problem getting/inserting data from/to database.

Error I get is `'timestamp with time zone' literal cannot be generated for Local DateTime: a UTC DateTime is required`
I tried `$"DateField >= \"{MyQyeryDate}"\"` and `$"DateField >= DateTime(\"{MyQyeryDate}"\)"` also `$"DateField >= DateTime(\"{MyQyeryDate.ToString()}"\)"`.
I tried setting DateTime.Kind to UTC, but none of the combination works for me.
I tried also converting it to string representation that my PostgreSql Client shows in table view, like so `MyQueryDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffffzzz")` and then putting it to query but no luck.
It is probably something that I have overlooked and can be easly done but still I can't get it working and found no answers yet.
In versions before Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 6.0.0 query like `$"DateField >= DateTime(\"{MyQyeryDate.ToString()}"\)"` worked fine. I would prefer not to enable legacy behavior for npgsql.

Comment: Try without Dynamic.LINQ, which you have not mentioned here.

Comment: There's really not enough detail above to understand exactly what you're doing; but the error message indicates that you're providing a DateTime with the wrong Kind (probably Unspecified) for a `timestamp with time zone` property. Try passing in a DateTime with Kind Utc.